# How to load only few rows from a .npy file?

Tags: python, numpy, file, numpy-ndarray

I have a file X.npy of 11GB which I cannot load in my memory altogether.

Shape of X.npy is `(18873, 224, 224, 3)`

**Now I want to load only few rows (say 1024) `(:1024, 224, 224, 3)` from it. How could I do this without loading X.npy in my ram memory?**

I found no parameters in [np.load](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.load.html) to achieve this. Is there some another way around?

I guess this could be done using [np.memmap](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html), but I stuck using the offset parameter. It's acting wierdly. X.npy has dtype of 'float32'.

Comment: HDF5 is a file format that solves this. Take a look at the `h5py` python package.

Comment: So, us there any way to convert .npy into HDF5 format, without loading it into ram, as I have just 4GB of ram.

Comment: memmap could help converting the file

Answer (score 2):

Use the `mmap_mode` argument from np.load:

```
X = np.load('X.npy', mmap_mode='r')
```

With this, the ndarray will act exactly as an in-memory array, but without loading it into the RAM.

Comment: But I want to load only few rows. If I use memmap, then do     newX = X_train[:256, :, :, :],     then I am not able to modify newX.

Comment: Then use the 'w+' mmap mode to alter the contents on disk, or 'c' to manipulate it after assignment, but preserve the data on disk.

Comment: I want to use 'c' mode, but using 'c', it loads all data on my memory and thus crashes my pc. So, any way to use 'c', but only loading few rows of data (say 256 rows).

Comment: This shouldn't happen with the 'c' mode. I advise you to post a minimal example of your code so people can analyse it further.

Answer (score 2):

## [`numpy.memmap`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html?highlight=memmap#numpy.memmap)

```py
# 1GB of memory
>>> arr = np.random.rand(150000000,)
>>> sys.getsizeof(arr)
1200000096


# Persist and release memory
>>> np.save(file='arr.npy', arr=arr)
>>> del arr


# Load as mmap, no increase in OS memory utilization
>>> map = np.lib.format.open_memmap('arr.npy', mode='r+')
>>> map.shape
(150000000,)
>>> sys.getsizeof(map)
128


# Sort 1GB, no increase in OS memory utilization
>>> np.memmap.sort(map)


# No increase in OS memory utilization
>>> subset = map[9450:9453]
memmap([0.43270294, 0.18917757, 0.6921332 ])
```

> ##### [`numpy.lib.format.open_memmap`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.format.open_memmap.html?highlight=mmap#numpy.lib.format.open_memmap)
>
> Returns an [memmap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap); a lazy-loaded/ virtual view into the array on disk.

---

### Feature parity versus ndarray

The memmap [methods](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/search.html?q=memmap) allow for interaction with the object while retaining its lazy state:

- Overwrite values and flush to disk
- Seeking: indexing, slicing
- Rearranging: sorting, partitioning
- Filtering: searchsorted (essentially > and <)
- Matching: any, nonzero
- Casting: astype
- Dimensions: ndim, shape, reshape, T, flatten
- Summary stats: mean, max, min, var(variance)
- Arithmetic (along axis): sum, prod(multiply), argmax, argmin

  - No subtract, divide

However, the memmap class does not have full parity with the `ndarray` class. Performing ndarray methods on an memmap will cause it to be loaded into memory as an ndarray:

- Most notably: operand-based filtering e.g. >, ==, where
- char class for working with strings
- concatenate

---

### Performance versus ndarray

```
                +---------+---------+-------------------+
                | memmap  | ndarray | memmap vs ndarray |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------------------+
|          load |  524 µs | 2510 µs |   4.8x faster     |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------------------+
|          sort |   10 ms |   79 ms |   7.9x faster     |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------------------+
|     subset[:] | 2890 ns |  248 ns | -11.6x slower     |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------------------+
|     subset[i] |  894 ns |  182 ns |  -4.9x slower     |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------------------+
```

> Test conditions:
>
> - `%%timeit -r 10 -n 10`
> - 1M rows `np.random.rand(1000000,)`
> - wrote arr to npy
> - `load()` w and w/o `mmap_mode` argument
> - all subsequent ops on either memmap or arr
> - 2014 macbook pro w SSD

---

### Performance versus pandas

```
                +----------+------------------+
                | pandas   | memmap vs pandas |
+---------------+----------+------------------+
|          load | 18000 µs | 34.4x faster     |
+---------------+----------+------------------+
|          sort |   173 ms | 17.3x faster     |
+---------------+----------+------------------+
|     subset[:] | 23700 µs |  8.2x faster     |
+---------------+----------+------------------+
|     subset[i] | 84600 µs | 94.6x faster     |
+---------------+----------+------------------+
```

> Test conditions:
>
> - `%%timeit -r 10 -n 10`
> - 1M rows `np.random.rand(1000000,)`
> - wrote arr to df then saved as parquet
> - load from parquet
> - all subsequent ops on df in-memory
> - 2014 macbook pro w SSD

So without ever hitting memory, np.memmap is faster than pandas in every regard.

Comment: Generator that reads subsets from memmap array, and feeds them to sklearn partial_fit()

Comment: NVMe 5x faster than SSD, and NVMe is 60x cheaper than RAM